# Why do dynamic variables not work with a let and const declaration?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable with an object. If I declare the variable with var I can call it dynamically with a string from the windows object.

**works!**

```js
var obj_1 = {
  say: "Hello World"
}

str = "obj_" + 1
console.log(window[str])
```

**dont work**

```js
const obj_1 = {
  say: "Hello World"
}

str = "obj_" + 1
console.log(window[str])
```

Comment: Read the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#description It is clearly explained in the description on MDN.

Comment: `const` and `let` are not in the global scope

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between "let" and "var"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-var)

Comment: FYI: doing that is a bad pattern. Use an object or set.

Comment: "Global constants do not become properties of the window object, unlike var variables." [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

Comment: Thanks at all commentors. now i understand! @epascarello Can you explain how it would look, please?

Comment: no different than window. except you store the things in the set or object. `const data = { obj_ 1: 1, obj_ 2: 2 };` and access it like you did. `console.log(data[str]);`

Comment: @epascarello That makes total sense! Thank you very much!